# Instead of marking rejected migrations [​Closed] can we mark them [Rejected Migration]?

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, deleted-questions, migration-rejection

On the *nope, haha, we were just kidding, that question doesn't belong here* target site (as opposed to the origination site where the question ends up after rejection), sometimes there are questions that didn't fit to begin with. What happens is they get closed, at which point the migration is rejected and it goes from the target site back to the origination site.

On the target site:

Sometimes the fact that a migration gets rejected is non-obvious, so instead of marking rejected migrations [Closed] in the title can we mark them [Rejected Migration]?

Some other designation?

Maybe we can derive a visual metaphor that indicates they've been locked and not just "closed"?

Ostensibly can we just auto-delete them once they fail migration by community censure?

Grace asks "what's wrong with the 'migrated from **site**' and the [closed]" as indicators that it's a rejected migration. That doesn't stop my users from flagging posts, and it doesn't always indicate to me that the post is "locked". So I try and respond to the flags appropriately (cleaning up broken windows) and instead get confronted with "this post is locked, can't do that, haha [insert nelson laugh]". That gets old fast when a simple indicator (or deletion on rejection) would prevent them from flagging and me from trying to moderate the flags.

Comment: perhaps the visual metaphor could involve a device that is opened with a key?

Comment: I thought the issue was that the locking was non-obvious, since the nature as a rejected migration is pretty clear from "migrated" and "closed" banners both present.

Comment: Not when posts are being flagged by end-users who want to see things converted to comments or when the system is auto-flagging poor quality questions.

Comment: D'you wanna clarify that you're talking about the question on the destination site, not the source?

Comment: No, I figure you'll just read my mind ;-)

Comment: How about a duplicate-like notice at the top of the post that says "This migration has been sent back to the origin site: [link to original question]"?